# Updating to Rails 3.2.2: How to properly move my plugin from the '/vendor' to '/lib' directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am upgrading Ruby on Rails from 3.1 to **3.2.2** and I would like to know what I should make and at what I should be care in order to properly move my vendor plugin (*note*: it is not a gem and at this time I am not planning to make that a gem) from the directory `/vendor` to `/lib` as well as wrote in the [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#what-to-update-in-your-apps):

> Rails 3.2 deprecates vendor/plugins and Rails 4.0 will remove them completely. You can start replacing these plugins by extracting them as gems and adding them in your Gemfile. If you choose not to make them gems, you can move them into, say, lib/my_plugin/* and add an appropriate initializer in config/initializers/my_plugin.rb.

I refer mostly to the "an appropriate initializer in config/initializers/my_plugin.rb": **What code should I put in that file?**

*More*: Do you have some advice or alert on making the above process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initializer should contain the appropriate requires and other startup related tasks that are necessary for your plugin to work correctly. It's difficult to help you without real code examples from your app but this link should help you get started.

http://code.coneybeare.net/how-to-convert-simple-rails-23-style-plugins

The example in the link requires the plugin (now in the lib directory) and adds a module to `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: My plugin is very simple and should work if I follow instruction in the linked blog post. Furthermore, my plugin has the same file system structure of the plugin in the post. However, I have a problem on step *6* when you must use the `require` statement: if in my `config/initializers/plg_name.rb` file I use `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/plg_name'` it doesn't work and I get the Phusion Passenger error `no such file to load -- /<MY_ABSOLUTE_PATH>/config/initializers/lib/plg_name`.

Comment: I also tried to use `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/plg_name/plg_name'` and `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/plg_name/plg_name.rb'`, but the problem still persists.

Comment: The error `/<MY_ABSOLUTE_PATH>/config/initializers/lib/plg_name` tells you that there isn't a file there and that's correct. You should be able to just use `require 'plg_name/plg_name'` because Rails will look in the lib directory.